# Robocopy batchscript keeps restarting

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, command-line-interface

I would like to backup my personaldata to a networkdrive within my private network.
To do so I tried using this script:

```
echo started robocopy

:: User
robocopy C:\Users\%USERNAME% Y:\BACKUP\C\Users\%USERNAME% /z /mir /xj
```

but the script keeps restarting...

```
PS C:\tools\Utility> .\Robocopy.bat

C:\Users\MyUser\SAVE\Skripte\Utility>echo started robocopy
started robocopy

C:\Users\MyUser\SAVE\Skripte\Utility>robocopy C:\Users\MyUser Y:\BACKUP\C\Users\MyUser /z /mir /xj

C:\Users\MyUser\SAVE\Skripte\Utility>echo started robocopy
started robocopy

C:\Users\MyUser\SAVE\Skripte\Utility>robocopy C:\Users\MyUser Y:\BACKUP\C\Users\MyUser /z /mir /xj

C:\Users\MyUser\SAVE\Skripte\Utility>echo started robocopy
started robocopy

C:\Users\MyUser\SAVE\Skripte\Utility>robocopy C:\Users\MyUser Y:\BACKUP\C\Users\MyUser /z /mir /xj

C:\Users\MyUser\SAVE\Skripte\Utility>echo started robocopy
started robocopy

C:\Users\MyUser\SAVE\Skripte\Utility>robocopy C:\Users\MyUser Y:\BACKUP\C\Users\MyUser /z /mir /xj

C:\Users\MyUser\SAVE\Skripte\Utility>echo started robocopy
started robocopy
```

It seems like its executing each step on the CLI.
How do I change this behaivor?

Comment: Don't call the script `robocopy.bat` when the exe is called `robocopy.exe`. Your script is calling *itself*.

Comment: Name your batch file something different. Robocopy is the name of the executable. Try `myrobocopy.bat`

Comment: Well ... that was easy. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never call batch files the same as system commands.

How cmdline and batch works:

First it will check local directory, where file is being launched from, for the file you are calling. Next it will check the system and user environment variable for the file you are calling.

In this case, you did not specify the full executable, `robocopy.exe` and it called the local file `robocopy.bat` as it was found first. Did you call robocopy.exe, it would not have launched the .bat, however as good measure, always call batch files something recognising what it will launch combined with that it does. I.e. `robocopy_backups.bat`